# How do you have an image split between two shapes that are on either side of the page? An image that can contain text that is directly editable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask, smartobject

Basically I need something like two smart objects that are on either side of a page and then an image splits between these two smart objects. It's hard to explain so I'll try my best to use imagery to represent what I mean.

[image]

So were these to two red circles are, I need these two directly linked in a smart object and then I need to be able to put text or anything here that splits between these two shapes. When I try and merge these as smart objects it still adds all that space between. Is what I need doable? Thank you.

Comment: I assume that you need to fold the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to do it like this:

- Create the Smart Object while the two images are *touching* each other.
- Enter the Smart Object and add the text.
- Duplicate the Smart Object (the duplicate of the Smart Object will refer to the original one).
- Put a mask on each of the Smart Objects to only reveal the left and right half.
- Position the two Smart Objects as you wish.

[image]

(As you can probably tell, I'm being too sloppy with the mask creation in this gif.)

This is very cumbersome to do in Photoshop, and actually I would say that Photoshop is the wrong tool for the job. Geometric layout like this should be done in a layout application like InDesign or Illustrator. Much easier.

Comment: I realize now that this might be for some box design in which case you will probably place the two halfs swapped.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. It's actually for folds in paper, a little project that I'm testing out. The two halves will meet together once the paper is folded. This helps a lot thanks for the taking your time to reply to this :)

Comment: You're welcome! The method can be useful in many situations. But for designs for print like this I strongly recommend that you look into using InDesign and Illustrator instead. Once you get the hang of it you won't look back.

Comment: Note taken! I appreciate it and I will definitely take the time to explore another program like illustrator next time. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey back again! Do you know how to flip everything within a smart object clipping mask on the main board so everything is upside down except the shape, but when you are within the smart object it's the correct way up? I don't want to have to flip within the smart object everytime, as want to be able to make this as simple as possible for future uses. Thank you!

Comment: Disable the small chain symbol between the layer thumbnail and the mask thumbnail.

Comment: Much appreciated, all done.